# Notice Array to string conversion in sugar charts

Tags: php, sugarcrm

How do I fix this error?

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\sugarcrm\include\SugarCharts\SugarChart.php on line 798

```
global $app_list_strings;
    $sortby1[] = array();
    foreach ($data_set as $row) {
        $sortby1[]  = $row[$keycolname1];
    }
    $sortby1 = array_unique($sortby1); <== line 798
```

I'm not familiar at all when it comes to php. Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
global $app_list_strings;
    $sortby1 = array(); // define an array variable. The [] syntax is used for appending data to an array not for creating an array type variable.
    foreach ($data_set as $row) {
        $sortby1[]  = $row[$keycolname1]; // assign value to array variable
    }
    $sortby1 = array_unique($sortby1); // remove duplicate values.
```

Note:- check yourself that `$app_list_strings` and `$data_set` will be correctly defined and have values. Thanks.

**`$sortby1[] = array();` adds an array as the first element of the array `$sortby1`, means your array starts like this:`Array ( [0] => Array() ...)` and since array_unique() treats all values as strings, it's trying to convert the first element, which is an array as string, which then throws this notice.**

Comment: Just for clarity, the difference is the removal of the `[]` from the name of the variable `$sortby1 = array();` (in case @hocuspocus31 couldn't spot it).

Comment: *Try this* And what did you changed it and why? Why did OP got the notice?

Comment: cool, that worked! thank you! question, why did you remove the `[ ]` from the name of the variable?

Comment: ^ See that's why you shouldn't just write "Try this", but I told you that already a few times!

Comment: *because  $sortby1[] is not the correct declaration type* That just doesn't explain anything!

Comment: You still didn't pointed out, why OP got the notice.

Comment: Now it gets even worse, because the linked question doesn't have to do anything, with the problem, which OP has. The linked question is a problem based in OOP syntax, here we don't have anything with OOP

Comment: 7 comments and 5 edits, if this only would be an exception.. (But in short: `$sortby1[] = array();` adds an array as the first element of the array `$sortby1`, means OP's array starts like this: `Array ( [0] => Array() ...)` and since `array_unique()` treats all values as strings, it's trying to convert the first element, which is an array as string, which then throws this notice )

Comment: @hocuspocus31 if the solution works for you then please mark it for the help of future visitors. thanks. Also what you asked is added into the answer. thanks.